# Error calling similar() in Sikuli

Tags: user-interface, automation, sikuli

```
l = find("Start_menu.png").similar(0.5).anyColor()
click(l)
```

The above is an excerpt from my code. "Start_menu.png" refers to an image of the Windows Start Menu.  I got the following error when I executed this:

```
File "C:\Users\VPRAVE~1.TSI\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-tmp8636618870597770744.py", line 1, in 
 l = find("1368426219510.png").similar(0.5).anyColor().anySize()
AttributeError: 'org.sikuli.script.Match' object has no attribute 'similar'
```

Could some one help me out with this? And could some one tell me how to use `anyColor()` and `anySize()`?

Answer (score 2):

`find` attempts to find something when it's called.  So what your code says, in prose, is "find something that looks like 'Start_menu', then make the thing you found 0.5 similar, then make that any color"

This is wrong--you can't set the similarity threshold after the fact.  Instead, call it as seen in the [Sikuli docs](http://doc.sikuli.org/match.html).

Instead, say

```
l = find(Pattern("Start_menu.png").similar(0.5))
```

Here's the same code arranged vertically:

```
pattern = Pattern("Start_menu.png")
pattern.similar(0.5)
l = find(pattern)
```

The other problem is your reference to the `anyColor()` function, which doesn't exist.  I see the code you're trying to run is from "Sikuli: Using GUI Screenshots for Search and Automation" (linked from the [Sikuli docs](http://doc.sikuli.org/#academic-papers)), but this function (and the syntax used in that paper) don't exist in any extant version of Sikuli.  You can see an open feature request for it on the [Sikuli launchpad page](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/99726).

This doesn't help you now, though.  I don't know of another visual automation package that *can* do `anyColor`.  If you wanted to use that feature for something, I suggest asking a new question where you describe the problem you're trying to solve, and someone may be able to suggest a work-around for that specific case.

Comment: I tried both, none of them worked.  I got an error saying "AttributeError: 'org.sikuli.script.Pattern' object has no attribute 'anyColor'".   Moreover, I didn't see any color change when I typed anyColor() and anySize() in Sikuli X-1.0rc3, on contrary to the predefined functions like click(), find(), etc

Comment: @Praveenkumar You're right.  I'd just assumed it was an undocumented function that you knew about and didn't check.  What made you think that an `anyColor` function exists?  Is there some documentation you're reading that references it?

Comment: <http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/projects/sikuli/sikuli-uist2009.pdf> . At page no.6 you would find both anyColor() and anySize() functions. This link has been shared at <http://doc.sikuli.org/#academic-papers>

Comment: @Praveenkumar It's a missing feature.  Strange that it's referenced in a paper from 4 years ago.  I have updated my answer to be correct and give some (unfortunately very limited) suggestions.